# How can I achieve a in-url routing in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to achieve a routing style such as:

mydomain.com/some-slug-text-a-123

The last digits is the `Id` of the particular resource and the `'a'` before that will represent the resource. Resources might be `a` for `Article`, `p` for `Product` and so on. Obviously for each resource I have a separate controller and my challange starts here.

In this case, apart from using the Home controller and serving all the content depending on the resource provided, is there a routing configuration specific to this scenario?

I am sorry if this has been an opinion based question but don't know how else to ask.

Comment: Maybe a URL rewrite is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to achive that. I'll will give you two examples, but I suggest taking a look into [Asp.Net Routing documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

#### Option 1 ([Multiple Convetional Routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#multiple-conventional-routes))

Map new route conventions on Startup.cs (method `Configure`)

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // Map articles (a)
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "a",
                pattern: "{*slug}-a-{*id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Article" });

    // Map products (p)
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "p",
                pattern: "{*slug}-p-{*id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Store", action = "Product" });

    // Default routing
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Create a controller and action that receive the parameters setted on your route convetion:

```cs
    public class BlogController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Article(string slug, int id)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
```

#### Option 2 ([Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis))

Map new route conventions on Startup.cs (method `Configure`)

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Add the attribute `[Route("")]` to your controller and/or action. I put the attribute just on action to simplify the example

```cs
    public class BlogController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/{slug}-a-{id}")] 
        public ActionResult Article(string slug, int id)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }

    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/{slug}-p-{id:int}")] // ":int means that the route will only accept an valid integer on this route; otherwiase will return NotFound
        public ActionResult Product(string slug, int id)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to write and explain! Sounds quite logical. Multiple Conventionel Routing looks cleaner which I was always afraid to fiddle with.